# Creating a custom prefix for different discord servers

Tags: discord.py, command

I am trying to make the bot have a prefix you can use for every server you want but when you use the command this pops up in the console

```py
return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] #recieve the prefix for the guild id given
KeyError: '882434407212925000'
```

Here is the code I used and the line it says it's failing

```py
def get_prefix(client, message): ##first we define get_prefix
    with open("prefixes.js", "r") as f: ##we open and read the prefixes.json, assuming it's in the same file
        prefixes = json.load(f) #load the json as prefixes
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] #recieve the prefix for the guild id given
```

Comment: The guild id doesn't exist in the prefixes var

Comment: @FloweyTF so could you tell me what I need to add then that would be nice

Comment: try debugging? print out the value of prefixes before you return the prefix?

Comment: Why is the JSON file named `prefixes.js`? Also, print the keys of `prefixes` whenever you load it in. If it's not there, you can make a function to add the guild ID and the default prefix as a key-value pair into the dictionary `prefixes` and later into the file `prefixes.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Wrong File Type

First of all, the file you are attempting to enter is a .js (JavaScript) file which is not a form of database. You are most likely looking for a .json (JavaScript Object Notation) file that can store data.

## Guild ID could not be found

Another reason why your code isn't working is because you are returning a non-existent dataset. In other words, the guild isn't in the prefixes file.

### Example

```py
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    try:
        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
    except:
        prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] = 'put default prefix here'}
        with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(prefixes, f)
        return prefixes(message.guild.id)]
```

Replace 'put default prefix here' with your bot prefix.

### Explanation

In the above example, I have added a try except into your code so that when an error happens (guild could not be found in dataset) it adds it to the dataset and returns the bot's default prefix as a placeholder.